# How i can save a multiple data into firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a problem when i have to insert a multiple data into firebase but it can't to save into firebase realtime database. Here my code:

```
Map<String, DataItems> users = new HashMap<>();
users.put("users1",new DataItems(value1,value2,n_value3,n_value4));
data.setValue(users);
```

and from DataItems class here this code :

```
public DataItems(String name, String category, int quantity, int prize) {...
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.prize = prize;}
```

and my firebase rules is

{"rules": {".read": true,".write": true}}

thank you all who help me find this problem

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is a bit unclear and it's also not clear what the specific issue is, is your code crashing? Giving an error? The [Firebase Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write) is a pretty good starting point on writing data. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update your question and we'll take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have inserted data in firebase realtime database as below:

```
//Declared globally in my activity
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
```

inserted data as "booking_id" where "booking" is parent node.

```
myRef.child("booking/" + booking_id).addValueEventListener(valueListener);
```

and added a listener to listen return value.

```
ValueEventListener valueListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //use dataSnapshot to get retured data

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

        }
    };
```

and detaching listener on destroy of my activity.

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        myRef.removeEventListener(valueListener);
      }
```

Hope this help you. For further reference you can visit official document as Muhammad mentioned url.

Comment: hmm, valueeventlistener can have to write a multiple data? i just know if datasnapshot use to be read firebase json. but, it can be write data with datasnapshot?

Comment: oh ok i'll be try after this. wow, i forgot rewatch this thread after i have focus on to another thread. thank you verymuch @KaluKhanLuhar